# Possible reasons why a Python script may be ran manually but not with crontab?

Tags: python, permissions, cron

I have a python script that It works when I run it manually with my user (not root) but not (nothing happens) when I schedule it with root crontab?Does anyone has any idea what that is the case?

the script download a file from some webpage and then put it in "folder 1" and then move it to a new folder, "folder 2" within "folder 1". Permission:

```
drwxr-sr-x folder 1 
drwxrwsr-x folder 2
```

Comment: Define "does not work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *many* reasons a script might run for you locally, under your user id, in your directories, and not run successfully under a daemon like `cron`. Here are the major ones, in order of likelihood (and ease of fixing):

1. **Location differences.** `cron` runs your script from a very different location than you. Usually something like `/var/spool/cron`, `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`, `/etc/crontab`, or `/etc/cron.d`. And it often runs with very spare `PATH` variables for automatic searching for an executable (see "environment differences" for more). So it's best if you provide a very explicit, absolute path to your script in the `crontab` entry. And if you use a shebang line (e.g. `#!python`) in your script, it's best you use an absolute path there as well (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/python` or whatever `which python` tells you is the correct path). This "be absolute!" commandment extends to any file paths your script tries to open or manipulate. Don't use relative file paths, because when run from `cron`, they won't be relative to the same place they will be when you run the script yourself.
2. **Environment differences.** If your script or any of its supporting modules requires certain [environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) to be set in a certain way (often to provide paths to programs to be executed, credentials for databases or other services to be run, or other configuration information), those variables are unlikely to be set the same way when you run from `cron`. You'll need to suss out what those variables are and either set them explicitly (from the `crontab`, in a "front-end script" you write just for running your main script from `cron`, or in the script itself).
3. **Security differences.** `cron` can run either as root, as a specific `cron` user, or as individual users (i.e., as you), depending on what `crontab` you add your entry to, and how `cron` is set up on your system. Unless you are using the "run as user" option, the security environment and permissions of the script when it is executing under `cron` control may be different from what your script expects.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is likely that only the owner of `folder 1` has write permission.

Comment: do you mean because of s? how can I change that? because I Have tried sudo chmod g+x <folder name> but nothing has been changed

Comment: Try `g+w` to change the (w)rite permission.

Comment: And (g)roup permission won't do it unless cron is running as a user in the same group.

Answer (score 0):

Script has different environment when you run it manually and when it is started by crontab.
May be you should check environment variables.